# How to use TS type as a value

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, types, enums

I have a TypeScript type which has a bunch of strings and it's defined like this:

```
type Regions = "" | "eu-west-1" | "eu-east-1" | "us-west-1" | "us-east-1" | "ap-southeast-1" | "ap-east-1"
```

I then later on in my code get the region from the URL via query-string parameters. Let's say that the retrieved region from URL is a variable named `region`

So i'm doing some validation in my code and I want make sure the `region` is of the type `Regions`.

So in order to do the validation my code says:
`if (region in Regions) { doStuff();}`

Which would work if Region was a variable with all those regions.

However since Regions is a type, it's throwing an error saying:
`'Regions' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`

Which I understand why, but how can I achieve what i want to do using or extending the `type Regions`

I really don't want to create another object or array of strings, I just want use my existing type to do this validation.

I did create an enum like this:

```
enum RegionsList {
  'eu-west-1',
  'eu-east-1',
  'us-west-1',
  'us-east-1',
  'ap-southeast-1',
  'ap-east-1'
}
```

and then did `region in RegionsList` but this is kinda duplicating my Regions type already, and there has to be a better solution that combines the 2. Any help/suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: TS is a compile time language. If types don't exist at runtime you cannot base runtime logic on types.

Comment: Use the enum RegionsList as the type.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't make a value from a type, but you can infer a type from a value.  That implies you should start with some runtime value and have the compiler infer the `Regions` type from it.

---

For example, you can make an array of valid region names:

```
const Regions = ["", "eu-west-1", "eu-east-1", "us-west-1", 
  "us-east-1", "ap-southeast-1", "ap-east-1"] as const;
type Regions = typeof Regions[number];
```

You can verify that the type `Regions` is the same as in your definition.  Then you can use the array to check that a string is a valid `Regions` (such as when you implement a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)):

```
function checkRegion(region: string): region is Regions {
  return (Regions as readonly string[]).indexOf(region) >= 0;
}
```

---

Or, if you want to use `in`, you can make an object whose keys are the values you care about, instead of making an array:

```
const Regions = {
  "": true,
  "eu-west-1": true,
  "eu-east-1": true,
  "us-west-1": true,
  "ap-southeast-1": true,
  "ap-east-1": true
}
type Regions = keyof typeof Regions;
```

And again you can verify that `Regions` is the right type, and use `in`:

```
function checkRegion(region: string): region is Regions {
  return region in Regions;
}
```

---

You *could* use an `enum` as above, but you'd need to be careful, since numeric enums have a [reverse mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) and so `"0" in RegionsEnum` is `true`, possibly surprisingly.  If you would still rather use that, it could look like this:

```
enum RegionsEnum {
  "", "eu-west-1", "eu-east-1", "us-west-1", "ap-southeast-1", "ap-east-1"
}
type Regions = keyof typeof RegionsEnum;
function checkRegion(region: string): region is Regions {
  return (region !== (+region) + "") && region in RegionsEnum;
}
```

(notice the extra bit of code making sure that `region` is not a "numeric string").

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5A1kg3gWAFBKVElgWQEEAnCrPAg+Ae2CgBckAlCAcwEsmokAXiQBtAERiANEjEQArgFoA7tBYKAjFJnyFEEKw1axcqMtWHpx03oObLIGAqgM5LABY21dmQ936vYgC6SPpIjMwsANy0dCwAnjDInLz8QkjxiQwAZhzcfMwiwHJgAEYQFIExBFlywPAs+WEe8GjJ+QAUFHlMAFxIrBQ8wFwAlH1dKcBIPAJtqTj4dARdLHIUU+1zzCECXSAAJkwANnH9LIPDIoEjAHRD+xAAHihZnd3AI0gAfMIADNGLAgAXzwMRBuBiRGgcEQqBKACsaICwvw2FsBMIFksCBI+uc5BBJFU6LJFCpbGI8RQCUTkTidJ5DFSacScSYzBTmYTWT5HM5XB5-Ez0tTuXTeX5OSKCcTwUsMkl3hikGgIHFsukEhANeiAUsanUGkwmhAWls3pM+gMhqNxu9prMlUjsUgVmsphNGkNcpMoHq6HKkIGoSRYQBRIpgZ10CCRn35KAR4rRpYSSw6ckBdOKRneKwcrMS-nuXNGXyl2XEhXx1LCVXqnIKnVKpNgf3VWr1RrwZqtd4W-JW842sau+0zGvbLHYt3rJAD40AQkEwnaAGpPUxPmuZGJPgAyfdjybTKbo1vtoNgpB4cFAA)

Comment: I ended up going for the enum version u showed me! Thanks a lot for the comprehensive explanation and typescript links!